# Django for loop range not working with lists

Tags: for-loop, django-templates, range, jinja2

In my `views.py` I set the value of `"range"` with the value of `range(10)` in my context. I'm trying to use range because I want to "iterate" through separate lists at the same time.

```
    context = {
        "summonerv3": summonerv3,
        "leaguev3": leaguev3,
        "champions": champions,
        "player_data": player_data,
        "range": range(10)
    }

    return render(request, "user/home.html", context)
```

Now I want to use the range to iterate from 0-9 in my template to access certain values in the lists that are also included in the `context{}` with a for loop

My template:

```html
{% for game in range %}
<p>{{game}}</p>
<div class="jumbotron jumbo-body col-12 p-3">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3">
   <img src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/7.22.1/img/champion/{{champions.game}}.png" height="80" width="80">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 text-center">
   <h6>Kills / Deaths / Assists</h6>
   <p>{{player_data.game.stats.kills}} / {{player_data.game.stats.deaths}} / {{player_data.game.stats.assists}}</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I added `<p>{{game}}</p>` to see if it's iterating properly, which it is.

Now what I expect is for "game" to be replaced by the current iteration number when trying to access data within my lists

So for the first loop:
`{{player_data.game.stats.kills}}` becomes `{{player_data.0.stats.kills}}`

The second loop:
`{{player_data.game.stats.kill}}` becomes `{{player_data.1.stats.kills}}`

but this doesn't seem to be the case. When I try this, no values are returned.

If I manually enter `{{player_data.0.stats.kills}}` it works fine so there's nothing wrong with my lists

Web page:
[image]
Every image link location is `http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/7.22.1/img/champion/.png`

If I manually change `{{champion.game}}` to `{{champion.0}}`  in the img src, it works fine